# AngularJS Directive for table header

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to write a directive to deal with changing an icon class for table headers.  What I would like is (what I believe anyway) the standard way of dealing with sorting by table headers.  The directive would add a link element and upon a user's click sort by desc and change the icon to desc, upon click again sort by asc and once again the the icon.  Here is what I have so far, but I am now at a loss for how to deal with the icon class as well as resetting other elements on the same table but outside of the directive's scope.  Any help would be great!

```
angular.directive("tableHeaders", function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    template:'<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></i>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        attrs.class = 'glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt';
    }
}
});
```

Here is what I have for the html side:

```
<th>First Name<a ng-click="newOrderBy('_firstName')"><table-headers></table-headers></a></th>
<th>Last Name<a ng-click="newOrderBy('_lastName')"><table-headers></table-headers></a></th>
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:orderBy:reverse>
<td>{{item._firstName}}</td>
<td>{{item._lastName}}</td>
</tr>
```

The order by is currently handled in the controller:

```
   $scope.newOrderBy = function(order) {
        $scope.orderBy = order;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };
```

Comment: Awesome! That is exactly what I was looking for, and so the transclude property just brings in whatever the directive is placed on top of correct?

Comment: Yes tranclude will ensure that whatever is inside the th tag will now be put under the span tag of the directive. See ngTransclude official doc (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngTransclude) or this article (http://blog.omkarpatil.com/2012/11/transclude-in-angularjs.html).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

What you need to do is for each element using your directive providing both an order and the current order (the one from your controller).

BTW I think your directive will be a better match as an attribute and not a tag. You can check the following code :

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive("sort", function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    template : 
      '<a ng-click="onClick()">'+
        '<span ng-transclude></span>'+ 
        '<i class="glyphicon" ng-class="{\'glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet\' : order === by && !reverse,  \'glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt\' : order===by && reverse}"></i>'+
      '</a>',
    scope: {
      order: '=',
      by: '=',
      reverse : '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.onClick = function () {
        if( scope.order === scope.by ) {
           scope.reverse = !scope.reverse 
        } else {
          scope.by = scope.order ;
          scope.reverse = false; 
        }
      }
    }
}
});
```

And the plunker that goes with it : http://plnkr.co/edit/P4cAm2AUGG36nejSjOpY?p=preview

The directive is used as such :

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th sort by="order" reverse="reverse" order="'name'">Name</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th sort by="order" reverse="reverse" order="'age'">Age</th>        
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: This is a helpful, clever approach, yet it does not offer full encapsulation: if you have multiple tables on a page, there is a risk you will end up sorting two tables at once if you keep the same values in the `by` and/or `reverse` attributes.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are intent on writing your own directive, you might consider looking at what is available. 
[ngmodules.org](http://ngmodules.org) shows some directives that are already set up for table headers.

Here are a couple options with some sample code to give you a feel for both.  They both look to be developed and very customizable.

### [ngTable](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/3)

[image: ngTable snapshot]

```
angular.module('main', ['ngTable'])
.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $filter, ngTableParams) {
    var data = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50}, ... ]

    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,            // show first page
        count: 10,          // count per page
        sorting: {
            name: 'asc'     // initial sorting
        }
    }, {
        total: data.length, // length of data
        getData: function($defer, params) {
            // use build-in angular filter
            var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                                $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) :
                                data;

            $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        }
    });
});
```

### [UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info/)

[image: UI Grid snapshot]

```
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.grid'])
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.gridOptions1 = {
    enableSorting: true,
    columnDefs: [
      { field: 'name' },
      { field: 'gender' },
      { field: 'company', enableSorting: false }
    ],
    onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
      $scope.grid1Api = gridApi;
    }
  };
});
```